# How does one pass in the table name used by a query (or join) as a query_param?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been attempting to pass in a a table name used by a query as a query parameter, but am not sure if there is a way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries):

> Query parameters can be used as substitutes for arbitrary expressions. Parameters cannot be used as substitutes for identifiers, column names, **table names**, or other parts of the query.

(emphasis mine)

You need to use an identifier instead of a query parameter.

Comment: ... or one can use tools like Potens.io :o) where everything can be parametrized

Comment: I think I'll just use airflow to template and fill out values in the query for now.